# How to use select in bash?

Tags: bash, unix

I am new to shell script and i was trying to execute below code -

```
select result in Yes No Cancel Exit
do
    if [ "result" == "Exit" ]; then
    echo $result
    exit 0
    fi
    echo $reslt
done
```

But code is not working expected, Not sure what is wrong with this code. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed $ in result, Try below -

```
select result in Yes No Cancel Exit
    do
        if [ "$result" = "Exit" ]; then
        echo $result
        exit 0
        fi
        echo $reslt
    done
```